# Cannot call value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried many times to call the values but it's failed. Maybe my code is not perfect enough.

loginprocess.php //this is the process to call the value

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$noic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['noic']);
$katalaluan = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['katalaluan']));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic = '".$noic."'  
AND katalaluan = '".md5."'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count==0)
     {
     echo "Tiada rekod di jumpai.<br>";
     echo "<a href='index.php'>Kembali</a>";
     }
     else
     {
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
     echo("<script>location.href = 'carianstatuspemohonresult.php?
     id=$row[noic]';</script>");
     }
     ?>
```

userinfo.php //this is to display the value

```
  <?php 
  include ("connection.php");
  $getId=$_REQUEST["id"]; 

  $query= "SELECT * FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic='$getId'";
  $result=mysql_query($query);

  <table width="50%" border="1" align="center">
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>NAMA</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["nama"];?></td>
</TR>

<TR>
<td align="center"><b>NO IC</b></td> 
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["noic"];?></td>
</TR>

<TR>
<td align="center"><b>KATA LALUAN</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["katalaluan"];?></td>
</TR>

<TR>
<td align="center"><b>JAWATAN</b></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["jawatan"];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>PERINGKAT</b></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["peringkat"];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><b>EMAIL</b></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
</td></table>
```

And sorry. I'm using mysql. Hope you can help me fix them even though I'm using the mysql. Also, hope you can understand the code without understanding the malay language.
Tell me if you need to see other code.

I've changed them. It's the same result. No values called. Hmmm.. :(

Comment: I need to look at your actual code seems like you are calling $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) twice

Comment: I've deleted the another one. But it's same also

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

You create a md5 value from a posted value, but aren't including it in your WHERE clause...  Try ...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE noic = '".$noic."'  
AND katalaluan = '".$katalaluan."'");
```

Comment: let me check it first

Comment: is it needed?why tho?

Comment: You had.. `WHERE ... AND  katalaluan = '".md5."'");  '       I assume not every record will have "md5" in that column    md5 is a function, you used it yourself to create a unique value from $_POST['katalaluan']

Answer (score 0):

You have two `while` fetching data on userinfo.php file:

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // <- Remove this one
 ?>

 <table width="50%" border="1" align="center">
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Later in the first file use proper quotes around "noic":

```
echo("<script>location.href = 'carianstatuspemohonresult.php?
 id=$row['noic']';</script>"); //<-- noic => 'noic'
```

It seems that you have to remove the first one.

EDIT: Also, you should follow the @DuaneLortie solution and use the variable you've created in your query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
                           daftar_pengguna
                       WHERE noic = '".$noic."'
                         AND katalaluan = '".$katalaluan."'");
```

Your code has a sintax error. `md5` is a function and you are using as a variable.

You should stop using `mysql_*` functions since it's deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. And finally, `md5` hash isn't secure for hashing passwords. Use bcrypt instead.

Comment: let me check it first